# JPA Join Fetch on dynamic columns

Tags: jpa

Is there any way to create one query that will Join fetch a dynamic columns given as a parameter.

```
<named-query name="getList">
    <query>select v from TableName v join fetch :field  </query>
</named-query>
```

I got a syntax error exception.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you dynamically build the JPQL.

In EclipseLink you can also define a join-fetch as a query hint.